# JQuery Minimize & Maximize HTML Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically I am trying to make a minimize/maximize div with jquery animation. I have a wrapper div named `leftFilterBox`. In leftFilterBox, there is another div to wrap all the contents named `filterContent`. So when I minimized the window, the filterContent should be collapse and the leftFilterBox will be shifted down at the same time when filterContent is collapse with jquery animation. Same goes to maximize. Here is my html code:

```
<div id='leftFilterBox'>
<div style='background: linear-gradient(#848484, #2E2E2E);color: white;line-height:2.2em;padding-left:5%;width:auto;font-weight:bold;'>Traffic Conditions

<div id='filterWindowNav'><img class='minMaxFilterBox' src='img/minimizeFilterWindow.png' onClick='minimizeFilterWindow();' />
<img class='minMaxFilterBox' src='img/maximizeFilterWindow.png' onClick='maximizeFilterWindow();' />
    <img class='closeFilterBox' onclick='closeLeftFilterBox();' alt='close' src='img/closeFilterWindow.png' /></div></div><br/>

<div id='filterContent'><span class='getLiveTrafficTitle'><center>Select date</center></span><hr width='85%'></div>

</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
#filterWindowNav {
float:right;
}
.minMaxFilterBox, .closeFilterBox {
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

And my JavaScript:

```
function minimizeFilterWindow() {
$('#leftFilterBox').css('height', '25px');
$('#leftFilterBox').css('top', '90%');
}
function maximizeFilterWindow() {
    $('#leftFilterBox').css('height', '65%');
    $('#leftFilterBox').css('top', '30%');
}
```

Here is my jsFiddle link: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PR4fp/1/)

Currently, my code is just collapsing the filterWindow by setting specific some css such as height and top. I wonder is it possible to use some jquery animation like `slideUp()` or `slideDown()` for enhcnacement because I tried it, but it does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your fiddle is broken.  Please correct it before we try and troubleshoot / make suggestions.

Comment: It works on my website with these codes. I not sure why it's broken in fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I couldn't get your code to work, but I organized it and added some click events to call your functions. I also added a background color to show the maximize effect is happening as it wasn't as obvious.

Updated [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PR4fp/4/)

```
$('#minimize').click(function(){
    minimizeFilterWindow();
});

$('#maximize').click(function(){
    maximizeFilterWindow();
});

function minimizeFilterWindow() {
    $('#leftFilterBox').css('height', '25px');
    $('#leftFilterBox').css('top', '90%');
} 

function maximizeFilterWindow() {
    $('#leftFilterBox').css('height', '65%');
    $('#leftFilterBox').css('top', '30%');
    $('#leftFilterBox').css('background-color', '#000');
}
```

And, the updated HTML

```
<div id='leftFilterBox'>
    <div style='background: linear-gradient(#848484, #2E2E2E);color: white;line-height:2.2em;padding-left:5%;width:auto;font-weight:bold;'>Traffic Conditions
        <div id='filterWindowNav'>
            <img id='minimize' src='img/minimizeFilterWindow.png'  />
            <img id='maximize' src='img/maximizeFilterWindow.png'  />
            <img id='close' alt='close' src='img/closeFilterWindow.png' />
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div id='filterContent'><span class='getLiveTrafficTitle'><center>Select date</center></span>
        <hr width='85%' />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sure, thanks a lot. But how could I make it expand at first. Then when I click on minimize, the filterContent will be collapse with animation and the left FilterBox title will also be shifted down when the contents collapse. Same goes to the maximize. Thanks.